# Select sub-categories of a specific category of a product in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, category, google-product-feeds, mage-googleshopping

I am trying to write code for generating Google shopping feed in Magento 1.

I want to get categories assigned to a product which are subcategories of a specific category (Designers).

How do I do this?

I want to populate this in the brand tag in the XML and we do not have any manufacturers but store them in categories with a parent category called 'Designers'

Comment: Does your Designer category have only one level sub categories?

Comment: yes, the basically represent the name of the manufacturers.

Comment: Check my answer which may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage to work by following code:

```
$designer_cat_id = 'YOUR DESIGNER CATEGORY ID';
$brands = array();
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
if ($categoryIds)
{
    $categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
    $categoryCollection->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',['eq'=>$designer_cat_id]);
    $categoryCollection->addIdFilter($categoryIds);
    $categoryCollection->addNameToResult();
    if ($categoryCollection->getSize() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($categoryCollection as $cat)
        {
            $cat_name = $cat->getName();
            $url = $cat->getUrl();
            // Write your code for xml node creation
        }
    }
}
```

***This code is not tested. This is basically an idea.***

Comment: Yeah this works perfectly. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Just add one more thing to your answer...re-initialize the $cat_name variable or else when a product does not have a child category of (in this case) 'designers', it still populates with the previous product's child category.

Comment: @SushantGurjar How to assign subcategory products to their respective parent category. eg: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXyaH.png how assign to parent category, here my parent category Electronics.

Comment: You can get parent categories of the categories your products are tagged in. Just write a query to tag them to their parent categories.